# How to see `diff` of all the files in one editor panel?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-history

I use VS Code and "git lense", "git history", "git graph" extensions. I made a lot of changes in a lot of files, and I can't see a way, using any of those extensions, to display all my changes in just one window.

I know I can click on a single file (when `diffing` with a chosen branch), but how to see the `diff` on all of them? Am I missing something, or maybe there is some other extension which can do that?

Comment: One not entirely satisfying answer is : run `git diff | code -` from the Terminal ...

Comment: You can then change the syntax highlighter to `diff` : choose `Change language mode` from the command palette (`Ctrl+K M` on linux), and select `Diff`

Comment: @LeGEC - thanks! That seems to be enough :) If you post it as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it :) Btw, it should be `git diff | code -` (with a space and a dash after 'code')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One not entirely satisfying answer is : run from the integrated terminal :

```
# the '[space][dash]' after 'code' is relevant :
# it tells vscode to write content received on stdin in a tmp file,
# and open that file
git diff | code -
```

The outpt will be opened as a `.txt` file, you can additionally change the syntax highlighter to "diff" mode :

- choose `Change language mode` from the command palette (`Ctrl+K M` on linux)
- in the dropdown list, select `Diff`